# Appium: How to copy paste text in textbox of in ios simulator

Tags: mobile, ios-ui-automation, appium-ios

I have iOS app in which i need to copy paste numeric text in texbox, to check copy paste is working for that textbox in automation.
How to copy paste text in iOS simulator using appium.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the link for help. It will work.
https://appiumpro.com/editions/16

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to have the `IOSDriver` instance.

`MobileElement textField = (MobileElement) driver.findElement(By.xpath("TODO xpath"));`

```
textField.setValue("5");
```

or

```
textField.sendKeys("5");
```

To get text from text field is also simple:

```
String textFieldValue = textField.getText();
```